# Carmichael numbers of order $4$

Tags: number-theory, pseudoprimes, carmichael-numbers

[Carmichael numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number) are known to have the property $p-1 | N-1$ for all $p | N$. It is also easy to find numbers $N$ such that $p+1 | N+1$ for all $p | N$ (these numbers lead to strong lucas pseduoprimes). Are there any examples of $p^2+1 | N^2+1$ for all $p | n$? I didn't find any prime $p < 1000$. Even without the prime restriction, I still wasn't able to find any integers with this property. The question is, find a set of integers $>1$ (not necessarily prime) $[a_1, a_2, a_3,...a_n]$ where $N=a_1*a_2*a_3*...*a_n$ and $(a_k^2+1) | (N^2+1)$ for all $k$?

Note: $N ≠ p$ and $N$ cannot be prime.

Comment: See comments. Of course this works for all primes which is why I mentioned Carmichael numbers.

Comment: And probably $N=n$, right?

Comment: Yes. To give you an idea of what I am looking for. For example $N = 2*7*17$  and the lcm of $(2^2+1), (7^2+1), (17^2+1)$  is $1450$, but $1450$ does not divide $N^2+1=56645$, so this would fail, for example.

Comment: @T.Rex To clarify, you search a Carmichael number $N$, for which we additionally have $p^2+1\mid N^2+1$ for every prime $p$ dividing $N$ ?

Comment: @Peter It's not a necessary condition (meaning $N$ does not have to be a Carmichael Number), however it is most certainly possible that $N$ is a Carmichael number.